# Firing an event when clicking a menu in Android

Tags: android, android-menu

I have a basic project and question. My start-up code is MainActivity.java, and menu belonging to it is *res/menu/main.xml*. Here is the content of it:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_add"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/menu_add_planet"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_config"
    android:orderInCategory="105"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/menu_config_planet"/>
```

When user clicks (or taps) on the *add planet* option on the menu, and I want the class to be activated.That class is *NewPlanet.java* Here is the content of it:

```
import android.app.Activity;
```

import android.os.Bundle;

public class NewPlanet extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

}
```

}

I anticipate that there must be a binding between the item element in the *res/menu/main.xml* and newPlanet but how? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want the class to be activated"?

Answer (score 1):

In your activity from where user will click the `add planet` option have the following:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent;
    switch(item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_add:
            intent = new Intent(this, NewPlanet.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            break;

    }
    return true;
}
```

Make sure you have the `Action bar`. You can show it by having `getActionBar().show();` in `onCreate()`. Also make sure you are not having both title bar and action bar at the same time.